# I think my team found a bug in 64bit compiler, can others either confirm or tell my why this is correct?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I have a simple clean room example of this possible bug.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool MyFalse = false;

        if (MyFalse)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

If compiled in x64 or AnyCPU (when prefer 32bit is set to false in VS2012) the if you put a breakpoint in the if block, it is always hit.

We tried it in VS2012, VS2010 and VS2008 and they all fired the if block when compiled in 64bit, yet in 32bit it does not fire the if block.

We looked at the IL for 32 bit and 64 bit versions and they look the same.

<del>We found this in production code because the if block was being ran and the exception was being thrown no matter what the value of the boolean variable, though in the simple example we cannot seem to throw the exception, it is happening in production code.</del>

<del>Since it is happening in production code, it is not just a debugger issue.</del>

Very strange behavior, but seems to not be acutally running any code in the if block.  Developer jumped the gun in assuming that was the exception he was seeing.

(All debugging is in debug mode - production is in release)

If the throw is commented out - the if block is not reached.

Comment: Sounds more like a debugger-putting-the-breakpoint-in-the-wrong-place bug.  **Is the exception thrown?**

Comment: Doesn't the IDE move breakpoints to the next line with code, in case the breakpoint is set on a line with no code. Since the compiler can remove the `if`, is that what is happening?

Comment: I have managed to reproduce this issue.  I put my breakpoint on the `if (MyFalse)` line and it drops into it and calls the throw exception.

Comment: I see what you're talking about. You can step onto the `throw new Exception()` line as if it were executed, though it clearly isn't as no exception is thrown and it won't trigger a breakpoint.

Comment: @NeilKnight: Does the presence of the breakpoint change the behavior (i.e. the exception only happens when there is a breakpoint, or always?)

Comment: Able to reproduce. If I debug in x64 and set the breakpoint in the beginning it will step into the if, but if I set it inside the if it will not hit. This does not happen in x86.

Comment: @Magnus: Are you seeing an exception?

Comment: @BenVoigt No the exception is not thrown. But it just looks like it would when you debug since it goes into the if.

Comment: Interestingly, I added a `Console.Write("Exception");` into the if statement and it's not outputting it when I debug the code.

Comment: @NeilKnight: In other words, it highlights the `throw new Exception();` line but it doesn't actually do it, right?

Comment: I really don't see why this question got a downvote

Comment: I updated the question with answers to your questions

Comment: If the program is being built in debug mode then that sounds like a bug; you can report it at connect.microsoft.com. If it's being built in release mode then that's to be expected; the debugger does a poor job of debugging code that isn't compiled in debug mode. (As Raymond says, I can't believe I had to say that. :-) )

Comment: Seems like you need a more complex testcase, that improperly throws the exception.

Comment: BTW, in the real code is the condition based on a local boolean variable or a shared one (e.g. class member, is it static or not)?

Comment: Good question - I am working with the developer on that now ...

Comment: I cannot, in a example app, get any of the code in the if block to affect anything outside the block.  I am begining to suspect that the developer jumped the gun on seeing such weird behavior in the debugger.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Okay, I see it.  This indeed goes wrong in the Debug build for the 64-bit debugger.  The key is to set the breakpoint exactly on the if() statement and then to start stepping.  It will *look* like the throw statement is getting executed.  But it that doesn't actually happen, actual code execution is proper.

To see what is happening, have it step into the throw statement line.  Then use Debug + Disassembly to see where it is actually located.  On my machine it looks like this:

```
       if (MyFalse)
00000040  movzx       ecx,byte ptr [rbp+8] 
00000044  xor         eax,eax 
00000046  test        ecx,ecx 
00000048  sete        al 
0000004b  mov         dword ptr [rbp+1Ch],eax 
0000004e  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+1Ch] 
00000052  mov         byte ptr [rbp+18h],al 
00000055  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+18h] 
00000059  test        eax,eax 
0000005b  jne         0000000000000088            // <=== Note this jump
        {
0000005d  nop 
            throw new Exception();
0000005e  lea         rcx,[5B848928h] 
00000065  call        000000005F65E9E0 
0000006a  mov         qword ptr [rbp+20h],rax 
0000006e  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+20h] 
00000072  mov         qword ptr [rbp+28h],rax 
00000076  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+28h] 
0000007a  call        000000005BE4A5D0 
0000007f  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+28h] 
00000083  call        000000005F73E36C 
00000088  nop                                     // <=== yellow arrow here
        }
        try
        {
00000089  nop 
            int i = 0;
```

You can even see it from the way the debugger groups the machine code instructions with the C# statements.  Note how the debugger is confused about the NOP at address 0088.  It thinks it belongs the compound if() statement.  So it puts the yellow highlight inside the block.  But the program has actually taken the jump at address 005b and has skipped the throw statement (addresses 005e through 0083).

Not so sure where to lay the blame on this one, can't blame the C# compiler or the PDB file since this operates correctly in 32-bit mode.  It smells like a jitter problem, notable is that the x86 jitter doesn't generate the NOP instruction.  You could also make the case that the jitter should have generated the JNE instruction to jump to address 0089.  These are but guesses, you can get a real answer at connect.microsoft.com

Just keep this quirk in mind until you hear back or we all get an update in a service pack.  The code is actually executing correctly so you only suffer a mild case of bewilderment.

Comment: "mild case of bewilderment" I've had similar things were debugger was showing me lies; I was more than mildly bewildered for a few hours. :)

Answer (score 10):

In optimized code, there is no strict correlation between MSIL and native machine code and source code.  This causes the debugger to sometimes highlight code different from what is being executed, highlight the same line multiple times while single stepping, or put breakpoints in places different from where you intended.

This is a fundamental problem with debugging optimized code, and represents inadequacies in the format of debug information.  There is no bug in either the compiler or the debugger.  You may have to resort to debugging in the disassembly view.

Comment: @Magnus: Side effect of the split compilation done in .NET: There are two phases of optimization: during translation into MSIL, and during JIT into native machine code.  Are you sure they are both disabled?

Comment: Just the one in build properties. (don't know any other)

Comment: @Magnus: You can use Reflector (or dotPeek, etc) to check whether the C# compiler added `DebuggableAttribute` and set `DisableOptimizations`.  There's also Visual Studio configuration to inhibit (or not) optimization when a debugger is attached.

Comment: Then why would it only do it for 64bit and not 32bit?

Comment: @saunderl: Because the machine code is different, the mapping between machine code and source code obviously also has to be different.  Beyond that, the x86 and x64 JIT compilers have different optimization logic.  Since you say you actually are seeing an exception thrown, it sounds like something else is going on.  But we need a testcase for *that*, and not just the debugger breakpoint in the wrong place.

Comment: And thats the problem, this is about 5 levels deep in try/catch and it is the outermost catch that has caught it. I am trying though ...

Comment: @saunderl: Can you try this: replace your `if (complicated-expression) { throw whatever; }` with `bool local = complicated-expression; if (local) { MessageBox(local); throw whatever; }` ?  Or write an entry to a logfile if you already have one set up.  Just make sure you're testing and logging a local variable.

Comment: Biggest problem with this answer is that it doesn't explain why this goes wrong in non-optimized code.  It is not the correct answer.

Comment: Hans, I answered the question that was existed when I wrote my answer, which said nothing about optimizer settings or anything else.  And I think I accurately described what you observed as well... poor mapping between source code and MSIL and native machine code.